# Run Android application from remote computer

Tags: remote-control, ssh

I need to run my Android application from a remote computer (in the same network) via SSH (not using ADB). How do I do that?

Comment: See also: [How to launch Google Keep from shell?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42217/16575). About how to find the activity to start, see e.g. [What is the main activity of Google Keep called?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42220/16575)

Answer (score 5):

You need to run an SSH server on your phone, such as [DroidSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=marc.scp.scp).

You can launch `adb shell` from the SSH session terminal, and then run `am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n <qualified-app-name>`.  For example, `<qualified-app-name>` is something like `com.android.settings/.Settings`.

Comment: You don't need to run `adb shell` before using `am`. `am` works like any other shell command, so you can run it from a SSH session directly, unless the SSH server dicks around with your `$PATH`.