# How to launch Google Keep from shell?

Tags: shell, google-keep

Using command from 
[this blog](http://learnandroid.blogspot.in/2008/01/run-android-application-from-command.html)

I want to launch keep from shell.

Comment: Related: [What is the main activity of Google Keep called?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42220/16575). If you know the answer to that question, it will answer yours as well -- in connection with the link you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay!  Thanks to a lot of [help from Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42232/30067), I was able to extract the name of the launcher activity from Keep's `manifest`.  So that means that the console command is:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.google.android.keep/.BrowseActivity
```

It goes without saying to make sure to preserve proper capitalization (casing).  If you want me to find out the names of any of the other activities (so your command launches *that* activity instead of the main page), just let me know!

Comment: @laggingreflex thanks for the fix, don't know how I missed that! :-O